# Insufficient Privileges on Recall Approval CPQ button on quote

Tags: permissions, approval-process, cpq

**Note: Everything is working fine for System Admin Profile but not for non-admin profiles**

I have one issue where **CPQ -> Recall Approval Quick Action** throws me an error.

**You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more information, see Insufficient Privileges Errors.**

All the other actions are working fine but recall approval is one which is throwing error.

If I manually update the Approval status to recall it is working fine, but only throws an error if I click on the quick action.

Kindly let me know what else I need to do to make the button work for non-admin profiles.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have followed the steps to [Create Advanced Approval Buttons](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.cpq_enable_aa_buttons.htm&type=5), make sure you have given users permission to the `RecallQuote` Visualforce page.